# Angular 6 environment scss

Tags: angular, angular6

I want environment.ts like replaceable files for style in my angular application. Which can be used to define base URL for different configurations I have in my angular 6 application.

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own themes similar to angular material but in general what you are trying to do is a bad idea because you are implying that you want different styles on DEV and PROD.

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: The reason i need to do this is because i am implementing angular 6 with laravel. So there are 2 different frameworks implemented together.